# How do I add a text box to the outside of a Matplotlib plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a `RandomForestRegressor()` plot with some important metrics (RMSE, MAE, and MAPE). I have the plot already but I need these metrics in a text box placed just outside of the plot. Here is what it looks like:

```
sn.set_style('dark')
# plot the model
plot = sn.scatterplot(plant_target, predicted_values_plant_1)
plot.set(xlabel='Given', ylabel='Prediction',title='Usine Random Forest Cross Validation (rain + debit + sierra)')
# generate and graph y = x line
x_plot = np.linspace(0,600,600)
y_plot = x_plot
plt.plot(x_plot, y_plot, color='r')
print('RMSE: '+ str(rmse_plant_1))
print('MAE: '+ str(mae_plant_1))
print('MAPE: '+ str(smape_score_plant_1))
```

Output:

[image]

How do I create a text box to add these metrics just to the right of the plot?

Comment: Does https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/placing_text_boxes.html help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `plt.text()`, as found in the [docs](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.text.html). For example:

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sn

plant_target, predicted_values_plant_1 = [100,200,300,400,500],[100,300,400,400,500]

rmse_plant_1 = 0.7
mae_plant_1 = 0.8
smape_score_plant_1 = 0.9

sn.set_style('dark')

# plot the model
plot = sn.scatterplot(x=plant_target, y=predicted_values_plant_1)
plot.set(xlabel='Given', ylabel='Prediction',title='Usine Random Forest Cross Validation (rain + debit + sierra)')

# generate and graph y = x line
x_plot = np.linspace(0,600,600)
y_plot = x_plot

# *** ADDING TEXT HERE ***
metrics = 'RMSE: '+ str(rmse_plant_1) + '\n' + 'MAE: '+ str(mae_plant_1) + '\n' + 'MAPE: '+ str(smape_score_plant_1)
plt.text(400, 100, metrics)

plt.plot(x_plot, y_plot, color='r')
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible for the text box to be set to the center-right just outside the plot without explicitly setting the loacation parameters?

Comment: The link above tells you how to place a text box in axes co-ordinates. Axes co-ordinates can extend beyond the axes...